# Is the language $L = \{0^m1^n: m \neq n \}$ not context free?

Tags: computer-science, automata, context-free-grammar

I have been trying to prove that this is not a context free language using the pumping lemma for CFLs. I have tried for hours but am not able to prove it. Is it a context free language or not? 
How to prove it?

Comment: It is context-free.  Hint: $L = \{0^m1^n \mid m<n\} \cup\{0^m1^n \mid m>n\}$.

Comment: Oh thanks for the hint. I have figured it out just now. The CFG is S->A|B; A->0|0A|0A1 ; B->1|B1|0B1